# Masonry Not Working at Certain Resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I have masonry working nicely, but it doesn't seem to work at certain resolutions. I've checked the code and all the margins/width's should be fine. Does this just happen in Masonry sometimes, or is there a way to fix this?

You can view a simple screenshot of this at https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHz46.png

Thanks!

Comment: How would you expect it to work at that resolution? I don't see any space for it to arrange the images any differently? (The Masonry plugin is supposed to still keep the element order, right?)

Comment: Masonry won't change the order for the images, which is probably what you're expecting it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with masonry is that it uses only a single dimension. When you want packing rectangles into two dimension you need something that works with two dimension hence there is a small gap at that resolution? This guy developed the perfect masonry: https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason